# OneToOne join produces "Parameter not set" in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

With the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NAMES")
public class Name {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "name", optional = true)
    private Event event;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class Event{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Name name;
}
```

And the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT n FROM Name n JOIN n.event e WHERE e=:uref
```

The query is executed with:

```
String queryString = "SELECT n FROM Name n JOIN n.event e WHERE e=:uref";
List<Name> result = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, Name.class)
            .setParameter("uref", userRef).getResultList();
```

I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        name0_.id as id1_ 
    from
        NAMES name0_ 
    inner join
        EVENTS event1_ 
            on name0_.id=event1_.name_id 
    where
        event1_.id=?
1-Aug-2012 3:18:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 90012, SQLState: 90012
1-Aug-2012 3:18:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
select name0_.id as id1_ from NAMES name0_ inner join EVENTS event1_ on name0_.id=event1_.name_id where event1_.id=? [90012-168]
```

Why doesn't the join work?

Strangely, this very similar query works:

```
SELECT e.name FROM Event e WHERE e=:uref
Hibernate: 
    select
        name1_.id as id1_ 
    from
        EVENTS event0_ 
    inner join
        NAMES name1_ 
            on event0_.name_id=name1_.id 
    where
        event0_.id=?
```

This was tried with Hibernate 4.1.5.SP1 and 4.1.0.Final

Note: the first query works in OpenJPA

Comment: Can you show us how you create the query and execute it? You aren't forgetting to set the parameter don't you?

Comment: I edited my answer. I do set the parameter properly. I even tried the equivalent query with the Criteria API and got the same result.

Comment: Edited my question not answer of course...

Comment: You've put entity "Name" twice instead of the "Event" entity, please edit the question... Perhaps the relation is not bidirectional... Anyway, the message error is rare as you are setting the parameter properly, I would start making some trial error, like using JOIN FETCH, adding spaces in e = :uref, making the query a named query, etc, and if all that fails, debug hibernate! sometimes empiricism is better than theory :P

Comment: I fixed the entity name. The relationship is bidirectional, but optional on one side. Removing optional=true does not solve the issue. As a workaround, I use the 2nd query which inverses the order of the join.

Comment: The second query has one redundant extra join to NAMES. The firs query looks right, is very strange that the error is in the parameters look up...

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the definition of equals and hashcode of your entities. See [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode)

Comment: Ok I removed the redundant join. The entities do not have hashCode and equals overrides. However, all the objects in the query are in the same Hibernate session. I guess I'll step in Hibernate code since all this works on OpenJPA...